# Two view in one Activity

Tags: android

i have following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"      
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/MainActivityCameraView"
    opencv:show_fps="true"
    opencv:camera_id="any" />  

<com.example.draw.DrawTransparency
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"        
    />
```

JavaCameraView is simple camera preview. DrawTransparency class:

```
public class DrawTransparency extends View {
.... 
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  // draw something
 }
 }
```

In MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView)   findViewById(R.id.MainActivityCameraView);       
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);                                    
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
}
```

My question is: why do I see the image painted by DrawTransparency although i did not invoke DrawTransparency in onCreate() method ? I would like to draw something (DrawTransparency class) on the screen, but only after the fulfillment of some condition..

Answer (score 0):

I have a rater small knowledge on android/java as i just startet with it..
but from what i see DrawTransparency is part of your activity_main.xml which you set in onCreate, so it's onDraw() will be executed.